# Integer remain integer but numbers with decimal will remain the decimal in my output answer?

Tags: python

My current code are as below:

```
num = input()
numlist = num.split(",")

def even(list):
    string = ""
    for number in list :
        number = float(number)
        if number %2 == 0:
             string += "~"+str(number)
    return(string)
def odd(list):
    string = ""
    for number in list:
        number = float(number)
        if number %2 != 0:
           string += "~"+str(number)
    return(string)

print "even numbers :" ,even(numlist)
print "odd numbers :" ,odd(numlist)
```

My output:
Even numbers:~56.0
Odd numbers:~3.0~1.0~5.9~12.6~8.9

Expected output:
Even numbers : ~56
Odd numbers:~3~1~5.9~12.6~8.9
thanks for help

Comment: my expected out put are 
Even numbers: ~56
Odd numbers:~3~8.9~7.7~5

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your input, your expected output __and__ your observed output.

Comment: Whats not working everything is fine in my PC

Comment: eidted , check my expected output

Comment: @Bharathshetty everything works but not my expected output

Comment: @Jack it'd be nice if you included your *current output* in your post so others don't have to copy and paste and run the code to see how it differs from your expected output.

Comment: @PM2Ring I thought python2 is different from python3 using input I used `input()` here.

Comment: @Bharathshetty My point was that in the previous version the `input` function wasn't actually being called.

Comment: @PM2Ring then the output won’t accept those with decimal

Comment: Why do you consider 5.9, 12.6, and 8.9 to be odd numbers? Strictly speaking the categories "even" and "odd" apply to whole numbers, it's not clear how to extend them to handle non-integers.

Comment: @PM2Ring my teacher wanted it. So this kind of problem can’t be solve right?

Comment: Strings split can be used here

Comment: It can be solved, you just need to give new definitions of "even" and "odd". :) I guess we can simply say that a number `n` is even in `n % 2 == 0` otherwise it's odd. And your code does exactly that.

Comment: But I think your main question is how to get rid of the `.0` from numbers that can be written as integers. Is that correct?

Comment: @PM2Ring using modulus over float is not at all recommended. Since reminder is only for integers. And Finally OP ends up in a string we can use some string functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you obtain string try this to use split `'.'` in your methods i.e :

```
 if string.split('.')[-1] == '0':
       string = string.split('.')[0]
```

Full Program :

```
num = input()
numlist = num.split(",")

def even(list):
    string = ""
    for number in list :
        number = float(number)
        if number %2 == 0:
             string += "~"+str(number)
        if string.split('.')[-1] == '0':
            string = string.split('.')[0]
    return(string)

def odd(list):
    string = ""
    for number in list:
        number = float(number)
        if number %2 != 0:
            string += "~"+str(number)
        if string.split('.')[-1] == '0':
            string = string.split('.')[0]
    return(string)

print ("even numbers :" ,even(numlist))
print ("odd numbers :" ,odd(numlist))
```

Sample output :

```
5,5.6
even numbers : 
odd numbers : ~5~5.6
```

*Note : Modulus should not be used over floats. Here it considers only integral part not the decimal.*

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to simply append the original string from `numlist` to the output string.

I've also changed the names of the arguments to your functions: you should not use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type.

```
def even(lst):
    string = ""
    for s in lst :
        number = float(s)
        if number %2 == 0:
             string += "~" + s
    return string

def odd(lst):
    string = ""
    for s in lst:
        number = float(s)
        if number %2 != 0:
           string += "~" + s
    return string

# Test

data = '3,1,56,5.9,12.6,8.9'
numlist = data.split(',')
print numlist
print "even numbers :" ,even(numlist)
print "odd numbers :" ,odd(numlist)
```

**output**

```
['3', '1', '56', '5.9', '12.6', '8.9']
even numbers : ~56
odd numbers : ~3~1~5.9~12.6~8.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your float is an integer, with the is_integer() method of floats. If it is an integer, you cast it to int, otherwise you leave it like it is.
So you can do something like this:

```
num = input()
numlist = num.split(",")

def even(list):
    string = ""
    for number in list :
        number = float(number)
        if number.is_integer():
            number = int(number)
        if number %2 == 0:
            string += "~"+str(number)
    return(string)

def odd(list):
    string = ""
    for number in list:
        number = float(number)
        if number.is_integer():
            number = int(number)
        if number %2 != 0:
           string += "~"+str(number)
    return(string)

print "even numbers :" ,even(numlist)
print "odd numbers :" ,odd(numlist)
```

input : 56, 3, 5.9, 12.6, 8.9

output: even numbers : ~56
odd numbers : ~3~5.9~12.6~8.9

Anyway, I agree with the others that it is really weird to use modulus with non integer numbers.